# Need information on Application Publishing Format in Huawei App Gallery

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

As I checked, Google has announced in below URL, that new apps will be required to published with Android App Bundle from August 2021. New Apps larger than 150 MB are now supported either by Play Feature delivery or Play Asset Delivery.

Reference link : https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

Does Huawei App gallery has any such plans to change the Application publishing to only Android App Bundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huawei AppGallery would accept apps released on either APK format or App Bundle. App Bundle with App Signing service is preferred. To support multiple architectures, multi-apk release is supported as well. Please refer to the following link for more detail
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-create_app

Answer (score 0):

There is no such plan to change the Application publishing to only Android App Bundle yet, but we recommended that developers release apps in the app bundle format.